# How to test DDR3 PC3 / DDR4 PC4 RAM works fine using a micro controller

Tags: microcontroller, ram

I am trying to make a device that can test if above mentioned RAMs are working without a problem. Does anyone have a place to read about RAMs and how to test them. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Modern DDR DRAM is not exactly easy to properly test. You might be in over your head here.

Comment: "Walking 1" should work no matter memory type. Though if you know more about the physical memory,  you could implement it in more or less meaningful ways. Ask the manufacturer what they recommend.

Comment: It really depends on what you want to test. Do you want to test for[JDEC Standard][https://www.jedec.org/standards-documents/docs/jesd-79-3d] compliance? Do you want to know if the bits that are written can be read out again? Even that might be quite a task with modern RAM for an MCU...

Comment: You might want to reaf this short E-Book first so you can find out what you need and what you want and make your question less broad: https://www.asset-intertech.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/testing-ddr3-memory-boundary-scan-jtag.pdf